# Conditionally auto number shipment (i.e. change shipment nbr before creation)

Tags: c#, acumatica

We have a case where we want to conditionally auto number shipments based on if they were created via the API or via the UI. I've got that part figured out, but I can't figure out the best way to set the ShipmentNbr. I know that I can update the ShipmentNbr in the RowPersisting event before it is saved to the database (like below), but that doesn't update the ShipmentNbr in the other related tables (SOOrderShipment, SOShipLine, SOShipLineSplit, etc). I also tried looping through the related records and updating them individually, but that didn't work either. I could do it in the RowInserting event, but that causes issues when dealing with concurrency. Is there any way I can update the ShipmentNbr for the shipment and its related records?

```
public void SOShipment_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{

        SOShipment row = (SOShipment)e.Row;
        if (row.ShipmentNbr.Trim() == "<NEW>")
        {
            row.ShipmentNbr = AutoNumberAttribute.GetNextNumber(sender, row, "SOSHIPMENT", DateTime.Now);
            // this works, but doesn't update related records
        }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145342/mix-manual-auto-numbering-sequences

Answer (score 3):

This was done for Purchase order but the methodology would be the same.

Create a new auto-numbering attribute that derives from the module specific as preference or base `AutoNumberingAttribute` if the page does not utilize a module specific version :

```
/// <summary>
/// Derived class of AutoNumbering Attribute -or- if available module specific version
/// </summary>
public class AAAPIDependantPOAutoNumberAttribute : PO.NumberingAttribute
{
    // Holds reference to PXGraph instance attribute is attached to.
    PXGraph _Graph;

    // Override base method so as to capture PXGraph instance reference.
    public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
        _Graph = sender.Graph;

        base.CacheAttached(sender);
    }

    // Override base method that populates new number symbol
    protected override string GetNewNumberSymbol()
    {
        // Checks graph instance to determine if from API call
        if(_Graph.IsContractBasedAPI)
        {
            // When AutoNumberAttribute NullMode is set to 'UserNumbering'
            // And GetNewNumberSymbol() returns an empty string
            // Attributes RowPersisting event will not override field with AutoNumber value
            NullMode = NullNumberingMode.UserNumbering;
            return base.NullString;
        }
        return base.GetNewNumberSymbol();
    }
}
```

Create a graph extension for the page in which you want dependant auto-numbering. Add a cache attached event replacing the base attribute :

```
public class AAPOOrderEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
{
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PO.NumberingAttribute))]
    [AAAPIDependantPOAutoNumber]
    protected virtual void __(Events.CacheAttached<POOrder.orderNbr> e)
    {
    }
}
```

You can see the result in the following screenshot top is via Autonumber bottom is via API :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured it out. I had some corrupt data which prevented the RowPersisting event from working correctly. Credit to Sergey here https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/05/auto-numbering-customization.html

Here's how I did it if anyone else needs to do the same:

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOShipmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
  {
        #region Event Handlers
       
        [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
        [PXDefault()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Shipment Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, IsReadOnly = true)]
       // [AutoNumber(typeof(SOSetup.shipmentNumberingID), typeof(SOShipment.shipDate))]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<SOShipment.shipmentNbr,
            InnerJoin<INSite, On<SOShipment.FK.Site>,
            LeftJoinSingleTable<Customer, On<SOShipment.customerID, Equal<Customer.bAccountID>>>>,
            Where2<Match<INSite, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>,
            And<Where<Customer.bAccountID, IsNull, Or<Match<Customer, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>>,
            OrderBy<Desc<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>))]
        [PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
        protected void SOShipment_ShipmentNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
        {

        }
       
        protected virtual void SOShipment_ShipmentNbr_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
        {
            SOShipment shipment = e.Row as SOShipment;
            if (shipment.ShipmentNbr == null)
            {
                e.NewValue = "<NEW>";
            }
        }
       
       
        protected void SOShipment_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e, PXRowPersisting InvokeBaseHandler)
        {
          
            SOShipment row = (SOShipment)e.Row;
            if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
                InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
            if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) != PXDBOperation.Insert)
            {
                return;
            }
            var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
            // don't auto number if shipment was created via api
            if ( !(httpContext != null && httpContext.Items != null && httpContext.Items.Contains("ApiContextId")) )
            {
                var num = AutoNumberAttribute.GetNextNumber(cache, row, "SOSHIPMENT", DateTime.Now);
                cache.SetValue(e.Row, "ShipmentNbr", num);
            }
            
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For customer, we can use :

```
  protected void Customer_AcctCD_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
  {

   var row = (Customer)e.Row;
   if (row==null) return;
   e.NewValue = "<NOUVEAU>";
  }

 protected void Customer_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
  {

   var row = (Customer)e.Row;
   if (row==null) return;

   if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) != PXDBOperation.Insert) {return;}
   string codeclient=row.AcctCD;
   if (codeclient.Contains("<NOUVEAU>")==true) 
    {
        var num = AutoNumberAttribute.GetNextNumber(cache, row, "CUSTOMER", DateTime.Now);
        cache.SetValue<Customer.acctCD>(row,num);    
    }
  }
```